# How to use loops to convert a decimal to binary?

Tags: python, binary

I want to write a program that converts the decimal numbers 0 to 9 into binary. I can code how to convert a decimal number to binary using repetitive division. However, I am having trouble with creating a loop that will print out the decimal numbers 0 to 9 in their binary format.

Here is my code

```
number = 0

remainder = 0
x = ""
while number (0,9):
    remainder = (number%2)
    x = str(remainder) + x
    number = number//2
   
    (x[::-1])
    print(number, "is the binary of",x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix of your code:

```
number = 123
remainder = 0
x = ""
n = number # don't work on the original number
           # you need it for the final print
while n > 0:  # wrong syntax for the condition
    remainder = (n%2)
    x = str(remainder) + x
    n = n//2
    #(x[::-1])  # this is useless
print(x, "is the binary of", number) # wrong order to print
```

*NB. You should also take advantage of `divmod`, instead of the two separate `%` and `//` operations*

Comment: so if `number=7`, your function returns `"111"` instead of `"0111"`, this is unexpected.  Your code should handle the zero padding.

Comment: @YeXu I don't see where this was a requirement, but you can easily use `print(f'{x:>04} is the binary of {number}')` to pad with a minimal size (here 4)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
number = 5
n = number
x = ""
while n:
    x = str(n % 2) + x
    n //= 2
    
print("Decimal:", number)
print("Binary:", x)
```

Output:

```
Decimal: 5
Binary: 101
```

Comment: so if number=7, your function returns "111" instead of "0111", this is unexpected. Your code should handle the zero padding.