# How to convert from decimal number to binary?

Tags: python

I have to write a program in Python that converts a decimal number to a binary. The decimal must be positive and the result must be put in a list.

Also, I cannot use the `input` function and the `.bin()`.

Starting from this:

```py
def dec2bin(number):
  binary_number = []

  return binary_number
```

I tried to use a while loop and a `.reverse()` function to do it but it's not working.

How could I write this program using a while loop?

This is what I tried to write but it's not working, what did I do wrong?

```
def dec2bin(number):
    binary_number = []

    while number =! 0:
        number = number // 2
        reminder = number % 2
        binary_number.append(reminder)
        binary_number.reverse()
       
        print(binary_number)

    return binary_number
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use loops to convert a decimal to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69702530/how-to-use-loops-to-convert-a-decimal-to-binary)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation:

```js
function toBase(num, radix = 10) { // only positive numbers
  var keys = ['', '', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  if (!(radix >= 2 && radix <= keys.length)) throw new RangeError("Radix argument must be between 2 and " + keys.length)
  if (!(num > 0)) throw new Error("Number must be positive integer")

  let output = [];
  do {
    let index = num % radix;
    output.unshift(keys[index]);
    num = Math.trunc(num / radix);
  } while (num != 0);
  return output.join("");
}
console.log(toBase("100", 2))
```